# How to leverage concurrency checking with EF 4.0 POCO Self Tracking Entities in a N-Tier scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, poco, n-tier-architecture

I'm using VS1010RC with the POCO self tracking T4 templates.

In my WCF update service method I am using something similar to the following:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyObjects.ApplyChanges(myObject);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works fine until I set ConcurrencyMode=Fixed on the entity and then I get an exception.  It appears as if the context does not know about the previous values as the SQL statement is using the changed entities value in the WHERE clause.

What is the correct approach when using ConcurrencyMode=Fixed?

Comment: POCO and STE ( self tracking entities ) are two different t4 generation strategies that can't be used together.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: They are no longer two different strategies.  You can have both.  See  http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/ or more specifically you can get the templates here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313

Comment: "Self Tracking Entities" is a totally different T4 template, see more information on the ado.net blog.  POCO != Self Tracking Entities.

Comment: I understand they are two differt templates but the ste templates seem to just add tracking support to the entities without any dependency on the EF.  So why wouldn't the generated class files be considered POCO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous values need to be in your object.

Let's say you have a property `ConcurrencyToken`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // stuff
    public byte[] ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can set `ConcurrencyMode.Fixed` on that property. You also need to configure your DB to automatically update it.

When you query the DB, it will have some value:

```
var mo = Context.MyObjects.First();
Assert.IsNotNull(mo.ConcurrencyToken);
```

Now you can detach or serialize the object, but you need to include `ConcurrencyToken`. So if you're putting the object data on a web form, you'll need to serialize `ConcurrencyToken` to a string and put it in a hidden input.

When you `ApplyChanges`, you need to include the `ConcurrencyToken`:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(myObject.ConcurrencyToken);
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyObjects.ApplyChanges(myObject);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Having `ConcurrencyMode.Fixed` changes the `UPDATE` SQL. Normally it looks like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyObject]
SET --stuff
WHERE [Id] = @0
```

With `ConcurrencyMode.Fixed` it looks like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyObject]
SET --stuff
WHERE [Id] = @0 AND [ConcurrencyToken] = @1
```

...so if someone has updated the row between the time you read the original concurrency token and the time you saved, the `UPDATE` will affect 0 rows instead of 1. The EF throws a concurrency error in this case.

**Therefore**, if any of this isn't working for you, the first step is to use SQL Profiler to look at the generated `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

The objects created as "Self-tracking entities" cannot be considered pure POCOs;

Here's the reason:
The STEs only work well if your client uses the generated proxies from the STE T4 template.
Change-tracking, and thus your service, will only work with these generated proxies.

In a pure POCO world (interoperatibility, Not all .Net 4.0 clients, .. ), you cannot put
constraints on you client. For instance, facebook will not be writing a service that can
only handle .Net 4.0 clients.

STEs may be a good choice in some environments, it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: It sounds to me like the definition of POCO is weak.  Plain Old CLR Object does not imply any specific version of the framework.  I realize the T4 template targets features of .NET 4.0.  I thought it spoke more to ORM framework dependencies.  Self tracking may or may not be a requirement of individual domain object that may have custom implementations of tracking.